# Any idea of why I get this git error: 1622754048270

Tags: git, github

Every time I try to clone a GitHub repo I get this git error: *1622754048270*.

I run: `git clone https://github.com/arnaubrichs/example.git`

and I get:

```
git clone https://github.com/arnaubrichs/example.git /Users/arnaubrichs/github/example-1 --progress
Cloning into '/Users/arnaubrichs/github/example-1'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/arnaubrichs/example.git/': Couldn't connect to server
```

Any ideas why this happens? (I'm running on Mac Mojave & VS Code)

Comment: You say you're cloning from GitHub, but presumably the website you've blanked out is not github.com. Is it some kind of authentication service, or are you actually trying to clone from a private server?

Comment: No, I just created a public repository in my GitHub account and tried to clone that from my computer. On Atom I get "code 128 stdout: stderr"

Comment: Ok, so what is the "[website]" that you've blanked out? If the repository is public, why the need for secrecy? Can you click [edit] and show some more of the commands you ran and the output you got? The more information you give, the more likely it is someone can help you; right now, we can't do much more than guess, because we've got a vague description of what you're trying to do, and a partial error message.

Comment: Sorry, just changed it now. Thank you

Comment: have you checked your internet connection? can you open the https url from browser? is your terminal have different configuration with browser (e.g.: http_proxy environment variable)

Comment: Internet and url are good. When I run this: git config --get-regexp http.*
I get: http.proxy https://github.com/arnaubrichs (my GitHub account)

Comment: Uh, that doesn't sound right. Why do you have github set up as a *proxy*?

Comment: I think so (when I run http.proxy I get my GitHub account address, github.com/arnaubrichs). How should I make sure I do?

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't clear. I'm saying that I think you have made a mistake somewhere which has set the GitHub URL as a proxy, because that is not something you would normally need or want to do. Do you remember setting that variable? If so, what were you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I did set that variable when I was trying to fix the issue. Now I've just removed it with git config --global --unset http.proxy. I do still get the same error message.